# Sequelize.js.How to use order with include in findAndCountAll function?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I always get an error when I use order and include in the findAndCountAll method:`Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

I have tried using `subQuery: false` to solve this problem, but it will affect pagination, when I use limit and offset I can't get the correct result.Thanks.

```js
    productDesignRecords.findAndCountAll({
        distinct: true,
        // subQuery: flase
        order: [
            ['updatedAt', 'DESC']
        ],
        offset: size * (no - 1),
        limit: size,
        include: [
            { association: 'productDesignDetails' }       
        ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Sequelize 4 I think your query should look more like this:

```
ProductDesignRecord.findAndCountAll({
  group: ['field'],
  order: [
    ['updatedAt', 'DESC']
  ],
  include: [
    { model: ProductDesignDetail, required: true }       
  ],
  offset: size * page,
  limit: size,
});
```

Comment: I have solved this problem with `separate: true`,`required : true` is not work.Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem and `separate:true` saved my day!